# why my form is doing postback when i am calling asynchronously?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i am using simple asp.net webpage with few fields on it and when the user click on submit button i am calling asynchronously and posting the data.

BUT, my whole page is posting back and i dont even see the message that i am trying to display if my data got posted succfully.

here is my page.

```
     <div id="status"></div>   
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID='lbl'  >Name:</asp:Label>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat='server'></asp:TextBox>               

    <asp:Label runat="server" ID='Label4'  >Host Name:</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHost" runat='server'></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label runat="server" ID='Label2'  >Start Date:</asp:Label>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat='server'  ></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label runat="server" ID='Label6'  >End Date:</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat='server'  ></asp:TextBox>        


          <ul>
          <li>
            <button id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" type="button">
              Cancel</button></li>
          <li>
            <button id="btnReset" name="btnReset" type="reset">
              Reset</button></li>
          <li>
            <button id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit">
              Submit</button></li>
        </ul>
    </p> 
    </form>
</div>
```

```
//Store new Contract Request Methods
    function processCompletedContactStore(response) {

       if (!response) {
           showErrorMsg('No Contacts Returned');
           return;
       }
       else { 
           if (response.Message == 'update') {
               $("#status").fadeTo(500, 1, function() { $(this).html("Updated successfully!").fadeTo(500, 150); })
           }
       } 
    }


function SavePage() {

    var request = buildNewContactRequest();

    ContactServiceProxy.invoke({ serviceMethod: "PostNewContact",
        data: { request: request },
        callback: function(response) {     
            processCompletedContactStore(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr, errorMsg, thrown) {
            postErrorAndUnBlockUI(xhr, errorMsg, thrown);
        }
    }); 
    return false; 
} 

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {     
            SavePage();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you binding the function call to the submit button? if so you need to return false at the end of the function, this stops the standard form post.

```
 $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {     
           return SavePage();
        });
```

Comment: @Abu Hamzah, although you are returning false from the function SavePage you have an inline function bound to the click event that does not return anything, try ammending to the snippet i added to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so on click you're doing:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {     
        SavePage();
    });
```

Where are you returning false?  Nowhere.  SavePage() returns false, but that never gets returned on the actual click function.  So you can either do:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {     
        return SavePage();
    });
```

In which case SavePage() will return false and that return value will be returned...

Or take out `return false;` from SavePage() and do:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {     
        SavePage();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: you typed as I was updating my answer +1 for the spot :)

Comment: @Pharabus.  Yeah, and I just realized I said "Where are you returning false?".  I never even said you had to return false in the first place, while you did.